# Puppet onlyif and unless conditional test from boolean data in Hiera and CLI script output

Tags: diff, puppet, hiera

I am running Puppet v3.0 on RHEL 6 and am doing package management via the `exec` resource.
I would like to add a number of control gates into my manifest via `onlyif` and `unless`.

First I would like to use booleans as defined in Hiera [ auto lookup function ].
Secondly I would like to use booleans from a bash script running `diff <() <()`.

Im using the following hiera data :

```
---
my-class::package::patch_now:
 0

my-class::package::package_list:
 acl-2.2.49-6.el6-x86_64
 acpid-1.0.10-2.1.el6-x86_64
...etc
```

and my manifest are as follows :

```
# less package.pp
class my-classs::package(
$package_list,
$patch_now,
){
   exec {'patch_packages':
      provider => shell,
      path => [ "/bin/", "/usr/bin/" ],
      logoutput => true,
      timeout => 100,
      command => "yum update -e0 -d0 -y $package_list",
      unless => "/path/to/my-diff.script 2>&1 > /dev/null",
      onlyif => "test 0 -eq $patch_now",
   }
}
```

How would I test the booleans (0|1) from Hiera and a CLI diff.script with `unless` and `onlyif` in the context above ?

Comment: Is there a reason your prefer exec over `package { "$pkg_name": ensure => "$pkg_version" }` ?

Comment: Using the package resource for a single package works fine, no problem, but it doesn't meet our requirements as these wouldn't be done as one transaction. Using the package resource with 1+ packages you would end up with two transactions, ie: `yum history info | grep -i 'Transaction ID'`. I also find it doesn't play well when there is a chain of packages dependencies if I were to set the desired state to `ensure => present,`. I am using `exec` here so the install 300+ packages in one transaction, which is also quicker compared to using the `package` resource for the same 300+ packages.

Comment: I see that you used onlyif and unless both, in which order are they executed ? I am looking for some clarification in a related issue..

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you mean to install all listed packages in one sweep if `$patch_now` is set.

You should not test for that using `onlyif`. That is meant to verify some state on the agent system. If the master is aware of your data, you should use conditionals in the manifest structure.

```
if $patch_now {
    exec { ... }
}
```

But do use `true` and `false` instead of `1` and `0` as the value for the flag - both `1` and `0` are equal to `true` in boolean context!

Your YAML looks funny, anyway.

To define a single value:

```
my-class::package::patch_now: false
```

To define an array:

```
my-class::package::package_list:
  - acl-2.2.49-6.el6-x86_64
  - acpid-1.0.10-2.1.el6-x86_64
  - ...
```

When you use the array in your class, you cannot just put it in a string such as `"yum update -e0 -d0 -y $package_list"`, for that will expand to `"yum update -e0 -d0 -y acl-2.2.49-6.el6-x86_64acpid-1.0.10-2.1.el6-x86_64..."`, without spaces between the elements.

To concatenate the elements with spaces, use the `join` function from the [stdlib](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/stdlib)
module.

```
$packages = join($package_list, ' ')
...
"yum update -e0 -d0 -y $packages"
```

I honestly don't get how your `diff <() <()` is supposed to work. The whole approach looks a little convoluted. I suspect that with a little tweaking, your diff script could probably perform the updates on its own (so that the `exec` just runs this script with different parameters).

**EDIT** after receiving more info in your comment.

To make this work cleanly, I recommend the following.

1. have Puppet transfer your Hiera data to the agent

   `file { '/opt/wanted-packages': content => inline_template('<%= package_list * "\n" %>') }`
2. The diff will then work like you suggested, only simpler.

   `diff /opt/wanted-packages <(facter ...)`

Just make sure that the `exec` requires the `file` and you should be fine.

Comment: Hi Felix, I tried the `if $patch_now { exec { ... } }` approach. However with arrangement I cannot use `require => Exec['...'],` from another resource. Think I found a workable solution with the Hiera boolean data, by replacing `test 0 -eq $patch_now",` with `onlyif => "echo $patch_now",` as one of the triggers to `exec {'patch_packages':`.

Comment: In regards to diff and the `my-diff.script`, I have a facter that build a list all RPMs installed on a node, then I have a list of desired state RPMs in Hiera and Im comparing the two lists in the form of `diff <(facter pkg_list) <(hiera data)` which is working fine from the CLI, so if the two lists doesn't match then diff would return a 1. I wanted to use this returned boolean from my script as a control gate with either onlyif and unless.

Comment: `echo $patch_now` will always return `0`, i.e. `true`. You might want to `require Class['my-classs::package']`, that is cleaner and safer.