# Puppet package management - Yum transactions

Tags: bash, transactions, puppet, yum

I need to `install/update/remove` a list of RPM packages via `Yum` from a local repo. The `install/update/remove` needs to happen collectively all as one yum transaction.

At present I aware of the following options for package management in Puppet.

1. Using the package resource type - job completed with 3 different yum transaction IDs

   ```
    class my-application::packages()
    {
     package { 'postfix':
      ensure => 'present',
     }
     package { 'postfix-perl-scripts':
      ensure => 'present',
     }
     package { 'mailx':
       ensure => 'present',
     }
   }
   ```
2. Using the exec resource type - job completed with 3 different yum transaction IDs

   ```
   class my-application::packages()
   {
     exec {'install_packages':
       provider => shell,
       path => [ "/bin/", "/usr/bin/" ],
       command => "/usr/bin/yum install postfix ; 
                   /usr/bin/yum install postfix-perl-scripts ; 
                   /usr/bin/yum install mailx ; ",
     }
   }
   ```
3. Using the exec resource type - job completed as 1 yum transaction ID

   ```
   # less /path/to/yum_transaction
   install postfix
   install postfix-perl-scripts
   install mailx
   run

   class my-application::packages()
   {
     exec {'install_packages':
       provider => shell,
       path => [ "/bin/", "/usr/bin/" ],
       logoutput => "true",
       command => "/usr/bin/yum shell /path/to/yum_transaction",
     }
   }
   ```

The above options 3 would work but is not scalable, when I have a vary large number of packages.

What alternative methods are available for package management in Puppet to enable me to completed all the work as 1 transaction ?

Comment: Unless there is some puppet limitation I'm not aware of you can list multiple packages to install on a single `yum install` command line. So you don't need to use a shell script or break the packages up into three `yum install` calls to do that.

Comment: That is correct I could also use `yum install $package_list` in the `exec` and source the list of RPMs from class variables, `Hiera` or even a flat file. The issue I have is that I need to do a `yum install` and a `yum remove` all as part of one transaction to get my server in the desired state, and the only way I was able to do this was via the `yum shell exec` as detailed above.

Comment: I saw your comment about that in the prose of your question but your examples all failed to actually show that and indeed I don't believe you can use the normal yum cli to construct a complex transaction of that sort (though yum is more than capable of doing that for you if the installations or removals require that to be done based on depdendencies).

Answer (score 2):

This is a very old issue with Puppet that has [no good solution](https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-1061) as of now.

Likely, your best bet is indeed to create an `exec` resource that installs multiple packages in one `yum` call. There is a [sort-of-related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24914087/puppet-onlyif-and-unless-conditional-test-from-boolean-data-in-hiera-and-cli-scr) where the user does this.

Comment: Sadly 9 years later this is still an issue with puppet without a good solution.

Answer (score -1):

```
packages = [ 'postfix','wget' ]
package { $packages:
   ensure => installed,
}
```

Comment: This creates multiple puppet resources, this is essentially equal to Option 1 by OP.